# Firefox settings via GPO

Tags: firefox, group-policy

I need to change a setting in firefox about:config over 900 or so odd systems. I will only accept a group policy setting to change this. We already have work arounds.

This is the setting I need to change.

```
network.dns.disableIPv6 = true
```

Without disabling IPv6 in windows or installing any software, can I change this via group police?

Comment: Good news. Firefox ESR is building a Policy Engine which should allow GP integration in the near future: https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2018/01/11/announcing-esr60-policy-engine/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot manage firefox with group policy. You have to use FrontMotion Firefox Community Edition which had Administrative Templates to manage all the settings in about:config.

The only solution with Group Policy with a regular installation of firefox would be to deploy a script to copy an edited "firefox.js" with the line "pref("network.dns.disableIPv6", true);" to "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref".

Comment: This was once true, but is no longer the case.  Firefox even has an Autoconfig option for all the preferences in prefs.js file.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this was resolve I'd like to mention I created a PowerShell script to do just this as well, works with any Firefox preference and many of the config files.

http://code.remyservices.net/powershell-firefoxpref/

Comment: Above link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer to this question...

Starting with Firefox v60 (I believe), I recommend starting here:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox-enterprise

There is now built-in GPO support for many (probably the most common) settings. MSI installers are also now available.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to manage and enforce Mozilla FireFox application settings using Group Policy.  It is a product called PolicyPak which is a group policy based desktop management system that integrates third party applications into Group Policy, allowing you to create GPOs to manage user application settings for FireFox and tons of other applications.  Using PP you can manage FireFox settings as effectively as you can manage IE with traditional group policy.  It even does it better because it locks down the settings as well.  PolicyPak has two ways to utilize it for free called community mode and trial mode so you can test it out.  Here is the page:

http://www.policypak.com/products/manage-firefox-with-group-policy.html

I want to disclose that I do work for the company that produces PoliyPak.